# Updating vim version on Fedora Core release 4 (Stentz)

Tags: vim

i am trying to update my vim version on Fedora Core release 4 (Stentz) FC4 machine.

Basically i would like to install few c-plug-ins which supports Vim >7. Current version that i am having is 6.3.

I tried manually downloading the vim-7.3 from the official site. I am following the CVS approach given here. 
http://www.vim.org/cvs.php

The installation went fine. 
After the installation when i type "which vim" from the installed directory it's pointing me to "./vim", but from if i type the same thing from any other directory say from home it's pointing to the default "/usr/bin/vim" which has 6.3 :( .

How can make the vim to point to use the version present in./vim instead of /usr/bin/vim

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make a copy of /usr/bin/vim
2. rename /usr/bin/vim to /usr/bin/vim.orig
3. ln -s ./vim /usr/bin/vim

Comment: More simply, just add the directory where the new vim binary exists to your `$PATH` before `/usr/bin/`.